# what's the most extensible/flexible FOSS e-commerce software? (or should I roll-my-own?)

Tags: e-commerce, customization, web2py, satchmo, spree

I need to build an internal order entry and tracking system for a grocery store which requires many of the features of existing e-commerce systems, such as product catalog, customer_to_order relations/views, movement reporting, order statuses, etc.  However, the first phase of the product is purely internal, so I don't need any online e-commerce features such as shipping addresses, postal rates or a payment gateway.  I've also got a bunch of business specific stuff that may not apply to a lot of on-line stores: complex product/customer discount system, lots of attributes for the products, a producer order-tracking flow (customer has an order with us and we have an order with the producer), and so on.

So I'm stuck wondering if I would be better off customizing an existing product, or rolling my own with a good web framework (such as Python/web2py)?  If it was a cut-and-dry online store, then the decision would be clear - but it's not.  So I'm trying to find the most extensible/flexible FOSS e-commerce software for prototyping.

The main contenders I've been considering so far are: Drupal/Ubercart, Django/Satchmo and RoR/Spree.  Ubercart is undergoing a complete re-write as Drupal Commerce, so that puts me off.  The Spree project looks clean and I like the ideas - but I'm already writing a product/customer ETL in Jython and don't want to balance the two languages - both Python and Ruby are new to me.

I don't like Magento's enterprise/community edition model.  And I've heard lots of complaints about osCommerce and it's variants.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

---

By the way, I think the gap between the feature-set I need and what I could get out-of-the-box from an existing e-commerce product is on the order of 30%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need that much extra functionality I reckon roll your own so you aren't constrained later.

Or better yet fork the current very basic (and easy to understand) web2py estore:
http://code.google.com/p/web2py-estore/
http://web2py-estore.appspot.com/ (demo)

Comment: As a matter of fact, I just came across the web2py e-store and am looking into it.  Thanks.

Comment: Cool! I am the administrator of the google code site could give you commit privilege if you wanted to extend it. But your description sounds different enough that forking might be preferable.

Comment: Thanks, Richard.  Maybe we could implement a few of the more general features before forking.  I'll follow-up if we decide to use web2py/e-store and get some code rolling.

Comment: I've decided rolling my own is probably my best option.  Starting parallel prototyping with Django and web2py to see which one is a better fit for my development style.